# Enforcing a specific JSON format for requests in PHP

Tags: php, json, rest, api, isset

I'm setting up an endpoint and I'm expecting to get big JSON requests. Of course, I want to make sure these JSON objects are in the correct format as per my documentation, so that I know when to throw a `400` status code. Here's an example:

```
{
"name":"John",
"surname":"Smith",
"id_no":82347239,
"residences":[
  {
    "address":[
      "12 Something Road",
      "Placeville",
      "Countrystan",
      "1234"
    ],
    "type":"house"
  }
 ] //etc
}
```

Currently I'm checking validity by using a massive set of `isset()` and `is_string()` etc checks. Is there a simpler way to make sure the format matches mine? For instance, can I set up a "template" JSON object and use some function to check that the formats match?

Comment: Have you got anything to show other than your example JSON? We help you fix what is broken, this is effectively asking us to write it for you, which is not what we are here for, we are a community of helpers, not a free code writing service

Comment: I would start by googling JSON schemas

Comment: @SamSwift웃 I'm here looking for frameworks, libraries or just simply ideas on how to solve the problem. No code required.

Comment: "*I'm here looking for frameworks, libraries or just simply ideas on how to solve the problem*" - that immediately makes this an off-topic question, A - it's not our job to do the research for you, asking for library recommendations brings too much opinion and noise. B - We won't write it for you, you need to show what you've done and tried, in a [mcve]. Please read the [help/on-topic] page for more info on what you can ask about to be on topic, see also [help/dont-ask] for what you should not ask about

Answer (score 0):

Not the ideal solution, but I wrote a little function that solves about half the problem:

```
/**
 * @param array $testme an assoc array as input to be tested
 * @param array $format the format assoc array to be tested against
 * @return bool whether or not $testme fits $format
 */
function validate_format(array $testme, array $format){

    if ($testme == null or sizeof($testme) == 0)
        return false;

    $test_keys = array_keys($testme);

    foreach (array_keys($format) as $k){
        if (!in_array($k, $test_keys))
            return false;

        else{

            switch($format[$k]){

                case 'string':
                case 'str':
                    if (!is_string($testme[$k]))
                        return false;
                    break;

                case 'integer':
                case 'int':
                    if (!is_int($testme[$k]))
                        return false;
                    break;

                case 'double':
                case 'float':
                    if (!is_double($testme[$k]))
                        return false;
                    break;

                case 'bool':
                case 'boolean':
                    if (!is_bool($testme[$k]))
                        return false;
                    break;

                case 'array':
                    if (!is_array($testme[$k]))
                        return false;
                    break;

            }

        }
    }

    return true; //all tests passed

}
```

Example usage:

```
$input = [
    'user_id' => '123',
    'password' => 'abc'
];
$format = [
    'user_id' => 'int',
    'password' => 'string'
];

$valid = validate_format($input, $format);
// false
```